# Real time Keras Object Recognition with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I tried loading a fine tuned model saved as a .h5 file to this script but it just kept loading in Jupyter Notebook. What is the correct argument to use so I can deploy the model on a real time camera feed?

```
 from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras import load_model
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import sys

import threading

label = ''

frame = None

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    global label
    # Load the VGG16 network
    print("[INFO] loading network...")
    self.model = load_model(PiVision.h5)

    while (~(frame is None)):
        (inID, label) = self.predict(frame)

def predict(self, frame):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).astype(np.float32)
    image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    image = image.reshape((1,) + image.shape)

    image = preprocess_input(image)
    preds = self.model.predict(image)
    return decode_predictions(preds)[0]

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if (cap.isOpened()):
print("Camera OK")
else:
cap.open()

keras_thread = MyThread()

keras_thread.start()

while (True):
ret, original = cap.read()

frame = cv2.resize(original, (224, 224))

# Display the predictions
# print("ImageNet ID: {}, Label: {}".format(inID, label))
cv2.putText(original, "Label: {}".format(label), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Classification", original)

if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
    break;

cap.release()
frame = None
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
sys.exit()
```

also keras does not have the option to save labels.pbtxt so how is it gonna print the labels?

is there a way I can create an instance to pass in the labels I have for my classifier